# C++ Windows Command Prompt C1083 "Cannot open include file: 'Magick++.h' No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, compilation, include, command-prompt, magick++

It has been over 4 hours since I made any progress at all, and searched documentation and links and frankly I'm out of ideas. So here goes.

**Background**

- I am compiling a C++ program in command prompt
- I am new to command prompt and fairly new to c++
- I am writing this program in Notepad++ (not VS) but have VS installed so I can compile
- I am trying to utilize ImageMagick through Magick++, a C++ API wrapper for it.
- Main program directory

  - C:/Program Files (x86)/CameraSoftware/myCameraProgram.cpp
- Magick++ directory

  - C:/Program Files (x86)/ImageSoftware/Magick++/lib/Magick.h

**Issues**

- I am trying to use the Magick++ API and so I want to include it
- I am just using this in the .cpp file `#include <Magick++.h>`
- I've messed around with numerous solutions that has worked for others but to no avail

  - fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Magick++.h': No such file or directory

**Problem**

- How do I correctly compile and link to 'Magick++.h' correctly through command prompt?
- Currently it is compiled as such

  - cl myCameraProgram.cpp /EHsc /link DSLRRemoteLib.lib
  - DSLRRemoteLib is a lib file located in the same directory and /EHsc and /link is required for it to function

**Other solutions**

- For visual studio projects, I believe you can add external directory paths to the project with some play around with the configurations, but I do not have that luxury using notepad++, so I really need to know how to compile this properly
- I have tried hard coding in myCameraProgram.cpp #include "COMPLETE_DIR_PATH/Magick++.h" and it will compile, but Magick++.h has more includes within it(eg `#include <Magick++/Include.h>`), and it will bring up C1083 error for each of the header files.

  - I've also tried hard coding the filepaths within Magick++.h and same problems with the next level of header files. So this not a solution.
  - I've also tried to tack on an additional argument to the /link the file in the compile line
  - `cl myCameraProgram.cpp /EHsc /link DSLRRemote "COMPLETE_DIR_PATH/Magick++.h"` but doesnt work
  - Also tried  `cl myCameraProgram.cpp /EHsc /link DSLRRemote /l "COMPLETE_DIR_PATH/Magick++.h"`
  - Along with multiple failed attempts.

Any help or advice or direction will be vastly appreciated, thanks!

======== EDIT ========

**Thanks for the tips everyone.**

- Using /I "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10\Magick++\lib" I could link the #include "Magick++.h" successfully, but it doesn't look anywhere else for other files.
- It cant find #include  which is in a subdirectory path "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10\Magick++\lib\Magic++\Include.h".
- "Magick++/Include.h" also makes a reference to another subdirectory in the parent directory.

**Progress**

- My current command prompt compile line is:
- cl "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10\Magick++\lib"
- Finds "Magick++.h"

**Issue**

- "Magick++.h" is a header file that includes 4 headers
- Upon compiling, it cannot find the other files which is in a subdirectory
- Is there a way to link ALL subdirectories and files under the path
- "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10" in a compile by any chance?

Comment: You need to use the [`/I` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx) to tell the compiler where the header files are located. The argument is the _directory_ where the header files are located.

Comment: Also, Program Files is probably not the best place to put files you're editing.  Consider using something under your user directory.

Comment: Hi I have tried moving my directory and also compiling now with  -  cl myCameraProgram.cpp /EHsc /link DSLRRemoteLib.lib /I "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10\Magick++\lib" (copied and pasted, shouldnt be wrong)  -  But no avail

Comment: @Luffy: put the `/I` option before the `/link` option, otherwise it gets passed to the linker (as the docs say, "The /link option and its linker options must appear after any file names and CL options").

Comment: So try `cl /I "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10\Magick++\lib" myCameraProgram.cpp /EHsc DSLRRemoteLib.lib` (note: you don't need the `/link` option to pass a .lib file to the linker - the `cl` command knows that a .lib file is an input to the linker)

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks for the tip. Using /I "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10\Magick++\lib" I could link the #include <Magick++.h> successfully, but it doesn't look anywhere else for other files, and it cant find #include <Magick++/Include.h> which is in a subdirectory path "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10\Magick++\lib\Magic++\Include.h". <Magick++/Include.h> also makes a reference to another subdirectory in the parent directory.

Is there a way to link ALL subdirectories and files under the path "C:\Users\ME\Documents\ImageMagick-6.8.1-10" in a compile by any chance?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev libmagick++4
```

Comment: Can you format the code (5 spaces in front of text), also there are no line breaks and it isn't clear if this is one single line command

Comment: The question is about Windows, not Linux.